# How to simplify $(5-\sqrt{3}) \cdot \sqrt{\left(7+\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How to simplify this:

$$(5-\sqrt{3})  \sqrt{7+\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

Dont know how to minimize to 11.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $7+\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2^2}\left(5^2+\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2+2\cdot5\cdot\sqrt{3}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the rules you know for working with roots: $\sqrt{a} * \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a \cdot b}$ and $\sqrt{a} / \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$ and $\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^n = \sqrt{a^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know the answer! (One might suspect it, for example, from a numerical calculation. )

Equivalently, we need to ask whether 
$$\frac{11}{5-\sqrt{3}}\overset{??}{=}\sqrt{7+\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}}.\tag{1}$$

To simplify the left side of (1), rationalize the denominator by multiplying top and bottom by $5+\sqrt{3}$. We get 
$$\frac{5-\sqrt{3}}{2}.\tag{2}$$
The square of this is equal to 
$$\frac{14-\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
It is immediate that the square of the right-hand side of (1) is also equal to $\frac{14-\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so we are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Justify each step in the following:

$$(5-\sqrt3)\sqrt{7+\frac{5\sqrt3}2}=(5-\sqrt3)\frac{\sqrt{14+5\sqrt3}}{\sqrt2}=$$

$$=\frac{22}{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt{14+5\sqrt3}}{5+\sqrt3}=\frac{11\sqrt2}{5+\sqrt3}\sqrt{14+5\sqrt3}=$$

$$=\frac{11}{5+\sqrt3}\sqrt{28+10\sqrt3}=11\frac{\sqrt{(5+\sqrt3)^2}}{5+\sqrt3}=11$$